# Secure Encryption Passing Sensitive Info to Server / API in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, security, encryption, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I have an app that uses Firebase/Cloud functions. On the client, I have users enter their:

- Bank Account Number
- Bank Routing Number

And (on my client) I pass those variable as parameters into a cloud function… like this:

```
final _cloudFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1');
  final _createCustomerAndAddBankingInfo = _cloudFunctions.httpsCallable(
    'createCustomerAndAddBankingInfo',
  );
await _createCustomerAndAddBankingInfo.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'routingNumber': routingNumber, // these are not encrypted, these are literally  the numbers e.g. `01234567`
      'accountNumber': accountNumber,
      'accountNickname': accountNickname,
      'accountType': accountType.toLowerCase()
    })
```

Then (on the server) I use the cloud function to pass that data to the Dwolla API (which already uses TLS) and I DO NOT STORE their routing / acct number anywhere in my database.

Since this is sensitive information, do I need to **encrypt it on the client** and then **decrypt it inside that cloud function**?

Or does cloud functions provide encryption when you pass parameters through as variables?

I scoured the docs online and I can’t find a concrete answer to this question.

I found this:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/server-side-encryption

...but I'm unsure if this applies just to reads/writes or if this also applies to functions.

I really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/is-it-ok-to-send-plain-text-password-over-https applies to your question:

> It is standard practice to send "plaintext" passwords over HTTPS. The passwords are ultimately not plaintext, since the client-server communication is encrypted as per TLS.
>
> Encrypting the password before sending it in HTTPS doesn't accomplish much: if the attacker got their hands on the encrypted password they could simply use it as if it were the actual password, the server wouldn't know the difference. The only advantage it would provide is protecting users that use the same password for multiple sites, but it wouldn't make your site any safer.

As long as your are communicating with Cloud Functions over HTTPS, encrypting Bank Account Number/Bank Routing Number is not achieving much.

Fortunately, you are already using HTTPS to communicate with your Cloud Function instance, as noted in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you will need to encrypt it on the client before sending it.
The way you would do this however can vary.

What I suggest is using a Cloud function to generate a one-use crypto hash and store it in a private non-readable database based on the user uid and a timestamp and then send it to the client.

The client then uses the secret key to encode the data and send it to a new cloud function that decodes it using the key from the database rather than having the key sent with the encoded payload

It is suggested that you store the encoded data with the timestamp mentioned earlier to validate/decode in the future in a two-step process so that if your database is ever compromised, the data is still encoded.

```
    var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "My Secret Passphrase");
    var decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedAES, "My Secret Passphrase");
    var plaintext = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

*Please note: that this is a simplified solution and you should look at additional steps to further enhance the encryption methods on top of this, including 3-way handshakes, randomized client/user based ID's, and other randomizing agents built within your app. While HTTPS is fairly secure, there is no guarantee that it is 100% secure.*